# How to measure the voltage over a transducer? aka how to measure ultrasound

Tags: amplifier, sensor, instrumentation-amplifier, ultrasound, transducer

I want to measure ultrasound.

For this task I bought a [sensor](https://www.ekulit.de/wp-content/uploads/datasheets/700620%20A-18P20.pdf), and an [instrumentation amplifier](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8226.pdf).

Apparently it doesn't work the way I thought because when I test it with a sample 40 kHz wave as input it does not get amplified but only phaseshifted or distorted when I adjust Rg (R Gain).

Shematic where ie(t) is the sensor.
[image: Measure]

- Should I use a specific shunt? At the moment its just a 100 ohm resistor
- What is a normal value for Rg? I tried it with a 250 kohm potentiometer but no value in that range helped.
- Am I using this instrumentation amplifier in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

> *Am I using this instrumentation amplifier in a wrong way ?*

Quite possibly (from your schematic).

As with any (maybe most) Instrumentation Amplifiers you need some DC bleed resistors down to 0 volts (mid rail) to remove bias currents because the inputs don't like to float: -

[image]

Bottom right is the picture I would reference in your particular case. Try 1 Mohm resistors.

> *What is a normal value for Rg ?*

[image]

I wouldn't be all that keen on using a potentiometer.

> *Should I use a specific Shunt ? at the moment its just a 100Ohm
> resistor*

100 ohm sounds low for a piezo based transducer - something like 100 kohm upwards might be a lot better but, to protect your inputs from possible over-voltage, have 10 kohm resistors in series with the inputs to limit over-current into the InAmp.

Comment: Like this: https://imgur.com/a/iYq81XC ? I tried it like this and with additional capacitors in series but that does not seem to work. Again I might have missunderstood you.

Comment: Yes like that but if you are trying to get an amplification greater than about 40 you'll be out of luck with that device at 40 kHz - look at fig 25 in the data sheet. It shows you that at 40 kHz you'll only get an amplification of 40 maximum no matter how small you make Rg. Is this the problem?